# Probability raffle question

Tags: probability

There is a raffle with prizes for first, second and third. There are $50$ tickets. A teacher buys $5$. What is the probability that;

$1$) wins first prize.

$2$) wins at least one prize.

Comment: The first one is pretty easy, because there are 50 outcomes and one of them is the first prize. Do you know the discrete uniform law?

Comment: sort of, i'm just stuck on how to work it out

Comment: The discrete uniform law states that if you have a discrete and uniform distribution (that is, discrete outcomes and each one is as likely as the other), then the probability of an event is equal to the number of favorable outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes. This can be applied in this case. What would you say, is then the probability of winning the first prize?

Comment: ummm...no idea. Can you tell me?

Comment: The number of favorable outcomes (in the first question) is 1. The total number of outcomes is 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$)The answer is $\frac{5}{50}=\frac{1}{10}$.

$2$)The second problem is harder, so I'll explain. We can first find the probability for  not winning any prize. the probability for not winning first prize is $1-\frac{5}{50}=\frac{9}{10}$, not winning second prize is $1-\frac{5}{50}=\frac{9}{10}$, not winning third prize is $1-\frac{5}{50}=\frac{9}{10}$. So the probability for not winning any prize is $\big(\frac{9}{10}\big)^3=\frac{729}{1000}$. So the probability for winning at least one prize is $1-\frac{729}{1000}=\frac{271}{1000}$.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Click the tick to accept my answer and you will get 2 reputation :)